# Django template does not detect instance of model

Tags: python, django

I added a Languages model to models.py:

```
class Languages(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    class Meta:
        order = ['order','id']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return ''.join([self.language, '-', self.level])
```

called

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate
```

and created a couple of instances:

```
python3 manage.py shell
In [1]: from resume.models import Languages
In [2]: Languages.objects.all()
Out[2]: <QuerySet [<Languages: Languages object (5)>, <Languages: Languages object (6)>]>
In [3]: Languages.objects.get(id=5).__dict__
Out[3]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7f0f21bb7668>,
 'id': 5,
 'language': 'English',
 'level': 'professional',
 'ordering': 1}
```

however my template does not detect any language:

```
<h2>Languages</h2>
{% for lan in languages %}
    <div>
        <h3>{{ lan.language }}</h3>
        <h5>{{ lan.level }}</h5>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

On the html of the site I see <h2>Languages but not the rest. Other models work fine.

As said, this is the latest model I added to models.py. I also called flush:
    python3 manage.py flush

This is part of showmigrations:

```
python3 manage.py showmigrations | grep -i langua
 [X] 0016_remove_language_personalinfo
 [X] 0018_delete_language
 [X] 0019_languages
```

How to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: oh no, that's the problem. it was so easy but .. I forgot to render the new model there. please write a quick answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `languages` into template context inside your view. Something like this:

```
context = {'languages': Languages.objects.all()} 
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```